# Get/modify address from client Endpoint config

Tags: wcf, .net-3.5

I'd like to store endpoint configurations in the .config file, but be able to modify the base address at runtime. EG: these are my endpoint definitions in app.config:

```
<endpoint address="net.tcp://BASEURI:1001/FooService/"
          binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_Common"
          contract="ServiceContracts.MyService"
          name="FooService" />

<endpoint address="net.tcp://BASEURI:1002/BarService/"
          binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_Special"
          contract="ServiceContracts.MyService"
          name="BarService" />
```

Each service uses the same contract (`ServiceContracts.MyService`), but live on a different port, different path, and sometimes a different binding configuration.

I want to be able to programmatically extract the address "net.tcp://BASEURI/FooService/", replace "BASEURI" with the address of the server, then pass this as the address to the DuplexChannelFactory when the client connection is created. EG:

```
string ServiceToUse = "FooService";

var endpointConfig = SomeFunctionThatGetsTheConfig(ServiceToUse);
string trueAddress = endpointConfig.Address.Replace("BASEURI", "192.168.0.1");
DuplexChannelFactory<FooService> client = 
    new DuplexChannelFactory<FooService>(ServiceToUse, new EndpointAddress(trueAddress));
```

I know that client endpoints don't support the **<baseAddress>** feature of Service endpoints, but my aim is to work-around that somehow so that I don't have to know what the rest of the URI or the binding is.

Note: I am not using a Proxy class, I'm using the DuplexChannelFactory directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily on your ChannelFactory, e.g.:

```
ChannelFactory<IFoo> cf = new ChannelFactory<IFoo>("EndpointConfigName");
string address = cf.Endpoint.Address.Uri.ToString();
address = address.Replace("BASEURI", "192.168.0.1");
cf.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(address);
```

Well, you have DuplexChannelFactory, but the idea's the same.

Comment: Perfect, worked the first time. Many thanks. Edit: WCF seems to convert the server part ToLower, so you have to match on "baseuri" rather than "BASEURI". Otherwise it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Implement an [IEndpointBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iendpointbehavior.aspx) and change the URL when being added.

You need to change the `ServiceEndpoint` in `ApplyClientBehavior`:

```
void ApplyClientBehavior(
    ServiceEndpoint endpoint,
    ClientRuntime clientRuntime
)
{
    endpoint.Address = ...
}
```

Comment: Where would I implement IEndpointBehavior? There's no proxy class being used, only the DuplexChannel.

Comment: While I managed to implement IEndpointBehavior and my ApplyCientBehavior method does get called when the channel is created, it's too late to change the endpoint address. The change doesn't take effect.

Comment: You don't want to take this approach because the IEndpointBehavior documentation says: "All of the IEndpointBehavior methods pass a ServiceEndpoint object as a parameter. This parameter is for examination only; if you modify the ServiceEndpoint object the execution behavior is undefined." See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iendpointbehavior.aspx